# Redirection loop on activating https on cloudflare enabled wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've a Wordpress site (with latest version). The site was running properly until I've activated force https from cloudflare! Cloudflare now a days provides free ssl and google also likes SSL enabled sites. That's why I've activated SSL from cloudflare and added page rule in cloudflare to force https.

I've also changed site's base url and home page url with https, but it still having redirection loop.

I don't have any idea if I'm supposed to post my personal site's URLs here or not. If required I will post the URL.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: BTW, I've not touched the default wordpress .htaccess file. I've just added a page rule in cloudflare as: `http://www.sitename.com/*` - 301 redirect to - `https://www.sitename.com/$1`

Comment: You can give me your url. I will look at http headers to see what's happening here. Will be a good starting point

Comment: Here is my site's URL [https://mtg.blogpipers.com/wp-admin/](https://mtg.blogpipers.com/wp-admin/)

Comment: Also here is the actual Cloudflare Rule `http://*.blogpipers.com/*` 301 Forwarding to `https://$1.blogpipers.com/$2`

Comment: To be honest, i expected to see a loop like `https` -> `http` -> `https` coming from a conflict between Wordpress and Cloudflare. Instead, this is the exactly same url that gets redirect again and again. This is totally weird. It's hard to tell you where the problem is at this stage due to lack of information. My advice: taking into account the loop behaviour, i cann tell you that Wordpress is not causing the issue here. Instead, i would check your Cloudflare rule (what if you disable it ?). Be aware to clear your browser's cache to see changes (old permanent rule are stuck in cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally adding the lines below to the wp-config.php resolved my issue.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}
```